# what is the difference between executing a batch and executing a bunch of statements in dbeaver

Tags: postgresql, dbeaver

Is there a fundamental difference in **DBeaver** between executing a script and executing the same statements as `"Execute Statement"` instead?

With the following **PostgreSQL** script

```
SELECT TXID_CURRENT();

SELECT TXID_CURRENT();
```

If I execute both as part of a single "Statement", it looks like they are executed within the same transaction
While if I execute the "script", they seem to be fired individually (not inside a common transaction)

Is this a feature of **DBeaver** or **PostgreSQL**?

Answer (score 2):

From the [manual](https://github.com/dbeaver/dbeaver/wiki/SQL-Execution):

**-> Execute SQL Statement.** This executes the SQL query under cursor or selected text and fills the results pane with the query results.

**-> Execute SQL Script** on the main menu or in the main toolbar. This executes all queries in the current editor (or selected queries) as a script. DBeaver parses queries one by one using a statement delimiter (“;” by default) and executes them consecutively.